# Connect on SQL Server with server & port

Tags: sql, sql-server, connection, port

I'm trying to connect to my SQL Server with host AND port, but no success.

I've found that the default port for its services is 1433, but I've tried strings like `.,1433` and `localhost,1433` but it doesn't work, even in the SQL Server Management Studio interface. Without setting port in the string connection it works with no problems.

I'm making an app that connects to a SQL Server database, and that's why I need this to connect to any port I choose, including the default.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If it's a new SQL install check it's configured to accept remote connections...caught me out!

Comment: Can you Telnet to that port? (http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003487)

Comment: Telnet fails on "localhost 1433". But I didn't change the default port. Where can I check the configured port?

Answer (score 1):

you should specify a protocol

> tcp:ip,port